# How to force a javadoc jar even though there is no (public) Javadoc?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I have a Maven multi module project of which some of the sub modules are only for internal use. I don't wish to publish any visible Javadoc for it, as it should not be used directly by 3rd parties. There is not a single public package in them (the package name itself has something like a.b.c.internal.d).

However, to release a jar to Maven Central, OSS Sonatype requires that all library jars have accompanying sources and javadoc jars.

**How can I force a javadoc jar to be created with a fixed index or so that tells the purpose of the sub module? A package-info.java comes to mind, but I have no public packages (all packages with the word "internal" in it are ignored).**

Comment: *"I don't wish to publish any visible Javadoc for it, as it should not be used directly by 3rd parties."*  - Surely, it is their business (not yours) whether they decide to do that?  If you feel you have a duty of care to advise people not to use your internal APIs, put a warning in the "internal" package info.  Or, make use of Java 9+ modules' ability to prevent accidental access to internal packages.  But it is best to assume that people who use your library will do so wisely.

Comment: They can do whatever they want, but it doesn't make me responsible for writing documentation on API that is not meant for public use. So I still have the problem with publishing the jar to Maven Central.

Comment: If you don't want to write javadoc comments, then don't.  The Sonatype rules don't require you to write the javadoc comments.  Skeleton javadocs would satisfy the requirement.   And it is probably less work than trying to figure out how to generate special empty javadocs.

Comment: @StephenC, for that there should be public API to begin with. All classes are ignored because of the package name containing the word "internal". I tried providing package-info.java in the root package, but the plugin will complain about missing actual classes to document.
> "And it is probably less work than trying to figure out how to generate special empty javadocs"
Well, generating a javadoc with one main entry explaining the purpose of the module and a link to the main documentation makes sense to me. Is that something that is possible?

Comment: Presumably it is doing that because you have an excludePackagesName element in the POM file that matches "internal".

Comment: @StephenC Of course, I'm using it as intended. I don't want my internal perusals to end up in public documentation (other than in the source itself of course) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Javadoc tool to produce a jar with non-standard content: use *maven-jar-plugin* instead to manually create one.

Initial solution taken from https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/generate-an-empty-javadoc-jar-file/

Here's the final solution I settled on and works generically for all submodules when configured in the parent pom:

Define two profiles:

- one to execute the standard javadoc plugin if no custom javadoc folder is present in the submodule (src/main/javadoc is missing)
- one to execute custom javadoc by means of jar plugin if a custom javadoc folder is present in the submodule (src/main/javadoc is present)

Maven config:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>standard-javadoc</id>
        <activation>
            <file><missing>src/main/javadoc</missing></file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <show>public</show>
                                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                                <detectOfflineLinks>false</detectOfflineLinks>
                                <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
                                <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                                <excludePackageNames>*.internal.*,testutil,demo</excludePackageNames>
                                <quiet>true</quiet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>custom-javadoc</id>
        <activation>
            <file><exists>src/main/javadoc</exists></file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                                <classesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/javadoc</classesDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

One *very* ugly work-around I found (and I won't accept this answer), is to simply trigger an error and set fail on error to false. The javadoc-plugin then proceeds with an empty target/apidocs folder and produces an empty submodule-javadoc.jar.

The easiest and simplest way to trigger an error I found is to create an empty package-info.java in the /src root folder. This produces the following build output:

> [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:jar (attach-javadocs) @
>   my-internal-module --- [INFO] 1 error [ERROR] MavenReportException:
>   Error while generating Javadoc: Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - No
>   public or protected classes found to document.
>
> Command line was: "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @argfile
>
> Refer to the generated Javadoc files in
>   'D:\workstation\my-parent-project\modules\my-internal-module\target\apidocs'
>   dir.
>
> org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Exit code: 1 -
>   javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
>
> Command line was: "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @argfile
>
> Refer to the generated Javadoc files in
>   'D:\workstation\my-parent-project\modules\my-internal-module\target\apidocs'
>   dir.
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5763)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2152)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocJar.doExecute(JavadocJar.java:189)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.execute(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:1911)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> ```
>
> [INFO] Building jar:
>   D:\workstation\my-parent-project\modules\my-internal-module\target\my-internal-module-6.0.0.beta-SNAPSHOT.2-javadoc.jar

With the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <show>public</show>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                <detectOfflineLinks>false</detectOfflineLinks>
                <doclint>all,-missing</doclint>
                <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                <excludePackageNames>*.internal.*,testutil,demo</excludePackageNames>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Though that satisfied my primary need (in a very ugly fashion) I would prefer a javadoc with one main custom entry where I explain the purpose of the module.